# How to solve Delphi OnGetText and OnSetText problem

Tags: delphi

I  am having a problem saving a TimeEdit value to a field that is an integer. The `OnGetText` procedure works but the `OnSetText` procedure is not updating the integer field in the database. This is what I have tried so far.

```
procedure TForm1.TesttimeTableTimeStartGetText(Sender: TField; var Text: string;
  DisplayText: Boolean);
begin
  Str((Sender.AsInteger/60):6:2,Text);
end;



procedure TForm1.TesttimeTableTimeStartSetText(Sender: TField;
  const Text: string);
Var TempStr  : String;
     TempVal  : LongInt;
     TempTExt : String;
begin
 TempText := Text;
 while Pos(' ', TempText) > 0 do
    TempText[Pos(' ', TempText)] := '0';
 if Pos(':',TempText) > 0 then
   begin
    TempStr := Copy(TempText,1,Pos(':',TempText));
    TempVal := StrToInt(Copy(TempText,Pos(':',TempText)+1,length(TempText) - Pos(':',TempText)));
    TempVal := TempVal + (StrToInt(TempStr)*60);
   end
  else
   begin
    TempVal := StrToInt(TempText)*60;
   end;
 Sender.AsInteger := TempVal;
end;
```

Comment: Onsettext isn't supposed to update the field in the table, it's just for display purposes.

Comment: Then the wiki page of embarcadero is giving out false information.According to their wiki page TFieldSetTextEvent is the type for event handlers that assign a field's value from a string. Or am i misunderstanding it completely?

Comment: No i do get any errors.I am using FireDac UDC with a binding navigator.

Comment: Any work around idea? If i have to explain why i am doing it this particular way it will lead to lectures about time which should not exceed 24hrs

Comment: I apologise, i was not throwing shade at you Tom.I really appreciate your time and help.I was talking in general about the inane debates about time formats.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you replace your current SetText procedure with one like the following.

**Update** I had missed the fact that you are using an FMX TTimeEdit so had completely misunderstood what you were trying to handle in terms of the `Text` value passed to your SetText handler - please see the **Updated code** section below.

Your version contained a few errors, which could probably have been avoided if
you were to break your code into smaller steps - it seems to me that your could
have much clearer code if you did that, as I have done below, and have individual
local variables for each part (before and after the `:`) of the processing.

Please note the code in the comments carefully.

**Updated code**

```
procedure TForm1.TesttimeTableTimeStartSetText(Sender: TField; const Text: string);
Var
  TempStr1,
  TempStr2  : String;
  TempVal1,
  TempVal2  : LongInt;
  TempText : String;
  P : Integer;
begin
  TempText := Text;

  //  following lines are better replaced by StringReplace
  //  while Pos(' ', TempText) > 0 do
  //  TempText[Pos(' ', TempText)] := '0';
  TempText := StringReplace(TempText, ' ', '0', [rfReplaceAll]);

  //  the following define is so that we can test the remainder of the procedure
  //  without continually entering data into the app's gui
{.$define Debugging}
{$ifdef  Debugging}
  TempText := '10:30';
{$endif}
  //  you obvously envisage dealing with the possiblity of the Text input var containing
  //  a colon, and it is simpler and cleaner to detect this only once and not
  //  try to deal with it 'on the fly' as your original code did

  P := Pos(':', TempText);
  if P > 0 then
    begin
      //  the following line is wrong because TempStr will include the colon :
      //  TempStr := Copy(TempText,1,Pos(':',TempText));
      TempStr1 := Copy(TempText, 1 , P - 1);
      TempVal1 := StrToInt(TempStr1) * 60;

      TempStr2 :=  Copy(TempText, P + 1, MaxInt);  //  Maxint always works here, no need for actual length
     //  TempVal := StrToInt(Copy(TempText, Pos(':',TempText)+1,length(TempText) - Pos(':',TempText)));

      TempVal2 := StrToInt(TempStr2);
      TempVal1 := TempVal1 +  TempVal2;
    end
  else
    begin
      TempVal1 := StrToInt(TempText);
      TempVal1 :=TempVal1 * 60;
    end;

  Sender.AsInteger := TempVal1;
end;
```

<s>**Previous code**</s>

```
procedure TForm1.TesttimeTableTimeStartSetText(Sender: TField; const Text: string);
Var
  TempStr1,
  TempStr2  : String;
  TempVal1,
  TempVal2  : LongInt;
  TempText : String;
  TempFloat1,
  TempFloat2 : Double;
  P : Integer;
begin
  TempText := Text;

  //  following lines are better replaced by StringReplace
  //  while Pos(' ', TempText) > 0 do
  //  TempText[Pos(' ', TempText)] := '0';

  TempText := StringReplace(TempText, ' ', '0', [rfReplaceAll]);

  //  the following define is so that we can test the remainder of the procedure
  //  without continually entering data into the app's gui
{$define Debugging}
{$ifdef  Debugging}
  TempText := '0.13:0.55';
{$endif}
  //  you obvously envisage dealing with the possiblity of the Text input var containing
  //  a colon, and it is simpler and cleaner to detect this only once and not
  //  try to deal with it 'on the fly' as your original code did

  P := Pos(':', TempText);
  if P > 0 then
    begin
      //  the following line is wrong because TempStr will include the colon :
      //  TempStr := Copy(TempText,1,Pos(':',TempText));
      TempStr1 := Copy(TempText, 1 , P - 1);
      TempFloat1 := StrToFloat(TempStr1);

      TempStr2 :=  Copy(TempText, P + 1, MaxInt);  //  Maxint always works here, no need for actual length
      //  TempVal := StrToInt(Copy(TempText, Pos(':',TempText)+1,length(TempText) - Pos(':',TempText)));
      TempFloat2:= StrToFloat(TempStr2);

      // you will need to edit the following to combine TempFloat2 with TempVal1
      TempVal1 := Round(TempFloat1 * 60);
    end
  else
    begin
      TempFloat1 := StrToFloat(TempText);
      TempVal1 := Round(TempFloat1 * 60);
    end;

  Sender.AsInteger := TempVal1;
end;
```

Comment: Hi @TomBrunberg.  Great minds think alike because I don't get it either.  As I've explained in my addition just now to my answer, the OP's SetText doesn't provide a colon-formatted text, so I'm somewhat in the dark how the colon would get there except by the user typing it, and what follows, in.  In any case, though, he can easily adjust the hard-coded test value to the format he actually intends.

Comment: Tom you are right .Rather to be understood as 20:25 is the right deduction.I did mentioned that i am using a TimeEdit

Comment: hi Martyn I tested your procedure and its working perfectly.Thanks I will mark as accepted if i could

Comment: Thanks, Louis.  Now that you have corrected my misunderstanding in your comment to @TomBrunberg, I have posted an update to my answer which has some simplifications to the code.  It can be simplified further and I will post a further update to to that later this evening.  Iit would be good if you could accept the answer - just click the 'tick' icon on its lefthand side.

Comment: Hi @TomBrunberg  I was being incredibly obtuse with my misunderstanding earlier and I appreciate the delicate way you dealt with it.